# android - Как настроить EditText, чтобы при adjustPan клавиатура поднимала не EditText а его корневого элемента?

Tags: android, клавиатура

Есть разметка с панелью печати внизу. Есть `SwipyRefreshLayout` - библиотека для свайпа не вниз а вверх. Так вот когда кружок обновления выходит снизу, и я открываю клавиатуру, то клавиатура как бы показывается над другим контентом. А мне нужно, чтобы она поднимала все. `adjustPan` мне ек подходит - не нравится, что `ActionBar` и статусбар скрываются. К тому же клавиатура встает под EditText, а мне нужно, чтобы она поднимала Layout, в котором он находится

Вот моя разметка

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/rootTag"
android:layout_gravity="bottom"
android:background="@drawable/image_2">

<ru.albatros.dindon.CustomSRL.SwipyRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipyrefreshlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:srl_direction="both">

    <ListView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:divider="#00000000"
        android:dividerHeight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"/>

</ru.albatros.dindon.CustomSRL.SwipyRefreshLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/connectPOST"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/send"
        android:id="@+id/send"
        android:background="#00000000"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:ems="10"
        android:lines="4"
        android:singleLine="false"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/send"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:hint="Ваше сообщение..."
        android:id="@+id/enter_message"
        style="@style/Widget.Group"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textColorHint="#000000"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: используйте adjustResize.

Comment: Если запустить кружок обновления и затем вызвать клавиатуру, то она закроет кружок обновления. А если сначала вызвать клавиатуру, а затем потянуть вверх то кружок обновления после скрытия клавиатуры остается в середине экрана.